# Read a txt file and compare values

Tags: java, string, eclipse, integer

I have been asked in my hackathon round to solve a question which was to read a .txt file from a server,and then build a logic to read it and print the highest scorer from all batsman given in that file.

txt file name was cricket.txt, and it looks something like this.,

```
Rohit Sharma|264
M.S Dhoni|198
Rahul Dravid|235*
```

like this every player name was in new line,and they want me to print the highest scorer from out batsman and highest scorer from not out batsman.
not out batsman scorer mark with the star mark followed by their score.
O/p format:

```
Rohit Sharma|264
Rahul Dravid|235*
```

Can u guys please help to solve this query, i have tried bt somehow getting Number FOrmat exception.

Note: Using Socket to read a file was not allowed.
(Please do the following in Java)

My code is as below(gives me Number Format Exception).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
URL url = new URL("192.168.1.3:8003/cricket.txt");
String data = new Scanner( url.openStream() ).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
int temp = 0;
for(int i=0; i<spData.length; i++) {
    String[] ns = spData[i].split("\\|");
    int temp1 = Integer.parseInt(ns[1]);
    if(temp < temp1) {
        temp = temp1;
     }       
  }
  System.out.println("Highest score is"+temp);
}
```

I am getting an Exception as follows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input                           string: "264
"   
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at interview.CricketScore.main(CricketScore.java:27)
```

Then i tried doing this to rectify the actual problem

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
String s = "Rohit Sharma|264";
String[] spS = s.split("\\|");
int j = 0;          
j = Integer.parseInt(spS[1]);
System.out.println(j);
}
```

but here i am getting the proper output.,why?how?same thing i am doing over there too, and i am recieving Exception.

Comment: The correct thing to do when you get an exception is not to quit and ask people how to do everything for you. The correct thing to do is to read the message and stack trace of the exception, see where it's thrown, what the exception means, find why it's thrown, and fix the code. You haven't posted anything that we could look at to help you with that.

Comment: Yeah, as if you are saying to add the code, i have the added code snippet too, please have a look at it., i am trying typecast it to integer(for example:264)then idk how 264 is not properly formated as an integer.

Comment: OK. So the exception tells you that it can't parse ns[1] as an integer, right? So, why don't you use your debugger, or simply add a println() in the code, or simply think about what your code is doing, to know what ns[1] is, and why it can't be parsed as an integer? You don't even need to do that, since the error message of the exception, that you didn't bother to post (and thus probably, to read), tells you what it is. Read the exception message.

Comment: Learn to use your debugger. Your split isn’t right.

Comment: ok sir, thanks for the suggestion ill try again.

Comment: Thank you Sir, now i got the answer.@JasonArmstrong and all of you

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer code is as follows:

```
package interview;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


public class CricketScore {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

   URL url = new URL("192.168.1.3:8003/cricket.txt");
   String data = new Scanner( url.openStream() ).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
   int out = 0;
    String outName = "";
    int nOut = 0;
    String nOutName = ""; 
    //System.out.println(data);
    String[] spData = data.split("\r");

    for(int i=0; i<spData.length; i++) {
        String[] ns = spData[i].split("\\|");
        if(ns[1].contains("*")==false) {
        int temp1 = Integer.parseInt(ns[1]);            
            if(out < temp1) {
                out = temp1;
                outName = ns[0];
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<spData.length; i++) {
        String[] ns = spData[i].split("\\|");
        if(ns[1].contains("*")) {
            String temp1 = ns[1].replace("*", "");
            int temp2 = Integer.parseInt(temp1);            
            if(nOut < temp2) {
                nOut = temp2;
                nOutName = ns[0];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Highest scorer from the Out batsman is "+outName +"|"+out);
    System.out.println("Highest scorer from the Not Out batsman is "+nOutName+"|"+nOut);

}
}
```